# How to condition the glyph of a code point based on the vowel gender in the same word?

Tags: font-design, font-forge

Here's the Mongolian Universal White Font [Link](http://hkuri.cneas.tohoku.ac.jp/project1/resources/css/fontface/opentype/MongolianUniversalWhite.ttf).

---

**BACKGROUND**

In Mongolian, vowels A (U+1820), O (U+1823) and U (U+1824) are masculine and vowels E (U+1821), OE (U+1825), UE (U+1826) are feminine. Masculine and feminine vowels cannot exist in the same word, so words are either masculine or feminine. The neutral vowel I (U+1822) can go into both masculine and feminine words and doesn't affect the gender. **If the only vowel in the word is the neutral I (U+1822), then it's considered to be feminine. This font gets this wrong and assumes it to be masculine.**

When located at the end of a syllable, either word-middle or word-final, **the consonant GA (U+182D) has masculine and feminine forms**. Manually, the different forms can be select by the Mongolian Free Variation Selectors FVS1 (U+180B), FVS2 (U+180C) and FVS3 (U+180D). This font can always detect and display the correct forms of word initial, middle and final variations, so here I'm leaving it out.

---

**PROBLEM**

The consonant GA (U+182D) at the **end of a word** have a feminine form [image], and a masculine form [image].

If a word has a feminine vowel E (U+1821), OE (U+1825) or UE (U+1826), the font detects the word as feminine and renders GA correctly.

However, **if the word only contains the neutral vowel I (U+1822), the font sees it as masculine and renders GA incorrectly**. For example, the word *bicig* (BA I CHA I GA, code points U+182A U+1822 U+1834 U+1822 U+182D) only contains the vowel I, and thus the word-final GA should have the feminine form. But the font renders it in the masculine form. (To manually render a feminine form, the sequence "GA FVS2" (+182D +180C) is needed)

In the following picture, the left one is "BA I CHA I GA", incorrectly rendering GA in the masculine form rather than the correct feminine form as shown at the right. The right one is reached by manually inputting "BA I CHA I GA FVS2", which shows the correct glyph but violates the (inter)national standards.

[image]

**Is there a way to code into the font the different forms of GA in situations where the only vowel is I?**

I tried FontForge to edit the font, but got lost at setting GSUB rules. Should it be a Contextual Alternates rule? How should the rule be expressed? I don't know how to set it and can't find a detailed tutorial. I'm also open to other tools as long as the problem can be tackled.

I also tried to figure out how to do it from the existing rules embedded in the font. Since the font renders words that contain a feminine vowel correctly, we should be able to locate the embedded rule that map the original GA to the word-final feminine GA. For example, "BA E CHA I GA" renders GA correctly. If we find this rule, then by a little twist I think we can extend it to words that only contains the neutral vowel I. However, I'm so new to font editing and failed.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GDSE! I'm not in any way capable of answering this, but I'm just wondering if you have tested the font in different software? I mean some advanced features might work in typesetting software like InDesign but fail in Word or a browser. If that's the case, it might not help editing the font.

Comment: @Wolff Good point. I just tested Firefox, Chrome, Safari and WPS Office. it consistently renders incorrectly.

Comment: Ah, ok. But what about a professional layout program like InDesign as I mentioned?